# How to pass argument to Jackson @JsonSerialize constructor?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialize a joda LocalDate to a string.

```
@JsonProperty("date")
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
LocalDate date;
```

However, that is getting three values like [2020, 1, 9] rather than a string "2020-01-09".

The LocateDateSerializer class documents multiple constructors, one with no arguments, and two like

> LocalDateSerializer(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter)

But I cannot figure out how to specify the constructor argument in the annotation so that I can invoke the LocalDateSerializer with a DateTimeFormatter argument.

Does someone know how to do that?

Comment: Did you look at the `setDateFormat` method of the `ObjectMapper` instance?

Comment: The serializer you're asking for is for the Java 8 Time API. Is this a legacy project or a new one?

Comment: To use serialiser with non-default constructor you need to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule`. See some examples: [How to write boolean value...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564639/how-to-write-boolean-value-as-string-in-a-json-array), [How do i use without any annotations...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104435/how-do-i-use-jackson-json-parsing-in-a-spring-project-without-any-annotations),[Convert java object with Element...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217671/convert-java-object-with-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-and-get-error-when-conver)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify format with `@JsonFormat`

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonProperty("date")
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
LocalDate date;
```

Comment: Not quite sure what was different about my environment but the @JsonFormat annotation also did not help.  The only way I could get this working was to go back to where the ObjectMapper is used and add a call to mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));  Then the dates came through as desired.  And fortunately there is only one such usage in this project.

Answer (score -2):

Try to put annotations on getter instead:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)   
public LocalDate getDate() {
            return date;
        }
```

Comment: Putting the annotation on the getter is probably cleaner, but doing that does not change the results.  I am pretty sure that I need to specify LocalDateSerializer with a formatter argument, but that is what I cannot figure out how to do.

Comment: Has you tried by self? Jackson annotations on getters can produce different results than on fields: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2345

Comment: Yes, I tried putting it on the getter.  Same results.

Comment: Don't know how you tested, but i just generated fresh spring boot project from https://start.spring.io/ then added simple code:  
@RestController
public class TestController {    
    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public TestDTO test() {
        return new TestDTO();
    }    
    public static class TestDTO {        
        private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();        
        @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)        
        public LocalDate getDate() {
            return date;
        }   }  }

and got expected: {"date":"2020-01-10"}